# Two variable equation, weighting of stock

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functional-equations

I am trying to find the weighting of stocks in a portfolio (both variables should be between 0 and 1 but added together should be 1).

the equation is:  $1.2353 = x(1.2) + y(0.9)$
I have it simplified down to where I can find $y$ in terms of $x$:

$1.2353 = x(1.2) + (1-x(0.9))$

But I don't know where to go from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the equation you got, the rest is simple algebra:
\begin{align}
1.2353 &= 1.2x + 0.9(1-x) \\
1.2353 &= 1.2x + 0.9 - 0.9x \\
0.3353 &= 0.3x \\
0.1117\bar6 &=x
\end{align}
Then, to find $y$:
\begin{align}
y &= 1 - x \\
&= 1 - 0.1117\bar6 \\
&= 0.8882\bar3
\end{align}
Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh wow, for some reason I wasn't think distributive property to switch around the way I had x(0.9) if I realized that, you are right, rest is simple. Thank you very much!

Comment: I just realized I made an arithmetic error.  Please see the updated version of my answer.